# Prevent d3 brush from firing a click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

D3 brush fires a strange click event on "*brushend*" even when the brush is not empty. I tried ***d3.event.stopPropagation()*** and ***d3.event.preventDefault()*** but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxcLc98g/) for demonstration .

```
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("fill", "none");


var brush_elem = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(d3.scale.linear().range([0, 200]))         
  .on("brushend", function(){ d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); });

svg.append("g").call(brush_elem)
  .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("height", 200);
```

Comment: .on("brushend", function() //brushend
 {
   d3.event.target.clear(); //-get rid of the brush   
 })); < see what that does

Comment: **d3.event.target** is the "*rect*" overlay created for the brush, not the brush itself. "rect" element doesn't have a **clear()** function. I have tried your ideas using **brush_elem.clear();** but the event is still fired.

Comment: this is what i have in my brushend function and mine works fine: .on("brushend", function() //brushend
 {
   d3.event.target.clear(); //-get rid of the brush
   d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target);
 }));

Answer (score 0):

[container element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermContainerElement)

An element which can have graphics elements and other container elements as child elements.

- a,
- defs,
- glyph,
- **g**,
- marker,
- mask,
- missing-glyph,
- pattern,
- svg,
- switch,
- symbol

g Element doesn't have canvas, it is container.

```
<style>
  g {
    fill: white;
    pointer-events: "all";
  }

  circle {
    fill: gray;
  }

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500" style="border:1px solid red;">
<g>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="100" stroke="red"/>
  <circle cx="220" cy="220" r="100" stroke="red" />
</g>
</svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script>
d3.select("svg")
  .on("click", function() {
    alert('svg clicked')
  })

d3.select("g")
  .on("click", function() {
    alert('g clicked');
    event.stopPropagation()
  })
 </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleCem/98ut4jac/